# how to vertically align div opposite to each other

Tags: html, css

I have placed two div opposite to each other using `display:inline-block`, now i want the div at right side should be centered with respect to left side div.

I have tried using following,

HTML:

```
<div class="header_first_above">
  <div class="first_above">
    <div class="logo">
      <p><img src="assets/img/logo_new.jpg" /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="icons">
      sd
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .header_first_above {
   width: 90%;
   height: 150px;
   background: #FFFFFF;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 5%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   top: 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
   box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
 }

 .header_first_above .first_above {
   width: 100%;
 }

 .header_first_above .first_above .logo {
   width: 20%;
   padding: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 .header_first_above .first_above .icons {
   width: 77%;
   display: inline-block;
   color: red;
   text-align: right;
   background: #F1B0B1;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   top: 10%;
 }
```

current output,

[image: Current Output]

required output,

[image: required output]

How to make this. I have tried a lot.

Comment: Try to use `vertical-align: middle;` and please, add your completed code instead of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `position:absolute` and use css `calc` for calculating the width of `.icons` and don't forget to [remove extra spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which is occurred by `display:inline-block;`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/zp94qn4w/)

```css
.header_first_above {
  width: 90%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
}
.header_first_above .first_above {
  width: 100%;
}
.header_first_above .first_above .logo {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
.header_first_above .first_above .icons {
  width: calc(100% - 20% - 20px);
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
  background: #F1B0B1;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_first_above">
  <div class="first_above">
    <div class="logo">
      <p>
        <img src="assets/img/logo_new.jpg" />
      </p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="icons">
      sd
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `display:table`

http://jsbin.com/sulopikuso/1/edit?html,css,output

Another solution is to use `display:flex`

http://jsbin.com/yififomiso/edit?html,css,output

In case of using Flex version be aware of browser support http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox and it's vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the height of the div you want vertically centered, one trick you can use is absolute or relative positioning with a negative top margin as so:

```
.header_first_above .first_above .icons {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: -75px;
}
```